# Flask-RESTful - Return custom Response format

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I have defined a custom Response format as per the Flask-RESTful documentation as follow.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

@api.representation('application/octet-stream')
def binary(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = api.make_response(data, code)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
    return resp

api.add_resource(Foo, '/foo')
```

I have the following Resource class.

```
class Foo(restful.Resource):

    def get(self):
        return something

    def put(self, fname):
        return something
```

I want the `get()` function to return the `application/octet-stream` type and the `put()` function to return the default `application/json`.

How do I go about doing this? The documentation isn't very clear on this point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What representation is used is determined by the *request*, the `Accept` header mime type.

A request of `application/octet-stream` will be responded to by using your `binary` function.

If you need a specific response type from an API method, then you'll have to use `flask.make_response()` to return a 'pre-baked' response object:

```
def get(self):
    response = flask.make_response(something)
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    return response
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return Flask response objects in your methods.

A response class allows you to provide custom headers (including the content-type):
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects

Comment: How would this work within the Resource class? Some code snippets will be helpful.

Comment: I'm looking at https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py line 475
dispatch_request and it's possible to return flask Response object

Comment: I stand corrected. This does not explain how to use the custom representations, however.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Martijin Pieters' answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20246014/1869562. Where you return a raw response object, Flask-Restful also allows you to set status code and headers in your return values directly.

So in your case, this should also work

```
class Foo(restful.Resource):

    def get(self):
        return something, 201, {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
```

The default mediatype for Flask-REstful is 'application/json', so put should work as is.

Comment: I have tried to use it but still getting `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`